# Searching Arrays with Realm (iOS)

Tags: ios, nspredicate, realm

Hiho,

I have a question about querying a realm database. I have realm-objects which contains features in a RLMArray. I want to find all objects which contains **all** features from a given array.
And in another case I want to find all object which have **one** of the features.

I try things like this (also with IN):

```
  NSArray *featureArray = @[@"feature1", @"feature2"];
  RLMResults* containedObjects = [MyObject objectsWhere:@"features CONTAINS %@", featureArray];
```

But get errors like: `RLMArray predicates must use aggregate operations`

I think the problem is, that realm have to check an array with an array for matching. In SQL I think a JOIN-Operation would be a good (not very efficent) way, but I can't found an equivalent operation in NSPredicate.

Thank you for every hint!

Answer (score 2):

As you can't store arrays of values in Realm, I guess that `MyObject` would have in that case a to-many relation / list property to a class `Feature`, which might be identified by their `name`.

`CONTAINS` is with NSPredicate not what you're looking for here. This is a [string comparison operator](https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/#string-comparison-operators).

You can use the `IN` operator, as seen below:

```
NSArray *featureArray = @[@"feature1", @"feature2"];
RLMResults* containedObjects = [MyObject objectsWhere:@"features.name IN %@", featureArray];
```

Note: you don't have to worry about performance, as links are first-class citizen in Realm, there are no expensive JOIN operations involved here.